# ImportError: No module named flask_mail

Tags: flask, importerror, flask-mail

```
from flask_mail import Mail,Message
from flask import Flask
```

I am trying to mail but import error is occurring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The are two packages by that name:

- The project found on GitHub and in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Mail) uses `flask_mail` as the package name; see their [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) and [project source code](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail).

  Their layout indeed requires:

  ```
  from flask_mail import Mail, Message
  ```

  This is a fork of the other project, but is currently actively maintained.
- There is a project on Bitbucket, and their [Flask-Mail documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/) and the [project source code](https://bitbucket.org/danjac/flask-mail/src/cbe68967187f604282c7a754db83ef3955135a52?at=default) show that the correct import is:

  ```
  from flaskext.mail import Mail, Message
  ```

  This project appears to be outdated and has not seen an update for almost 3 years now. The Github project names the same original author, it appears to be an updated fork. I'd stick with the Github project.

If neither works, then *there is no such module installed*, not in the location that the Python version running your Flask server can find.

Comment: the documentation says its flask_mail which i tried but even if i am trying flaskext.email i am getting same error

Comment: @user3340941: then what extension did you install? Because the documentation I found doesn't appear to agree with you. How certain are you you installed it correctly?

Comment: @user3340941: Yeah, it turns out there are two projects. Wonderfully confusing. I've updated my answer to reflect how both work.

Comment: @user3340941: I'd install the newer version from GitHub; with a virtualenv, make sure you use the `pip` installed inside of it to install the package, then verify that the `flask_mail.py` file is present in the `lib/python2.7/site-packages/` directory of the virtual env.

Comment: @user3340941: glad to hear that! Thanks for accepting the answer, you also *un* accepted again though. Anything missing?

Comment: @user3340941: or put it differently: double-clicking the V mark accepts, then unaccepts. Click just *once*. :-)

Comment: The module appears to be borked now. https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/issues/116

Comment: @karel It has not been renamed. The installed package name is not the same thing as the project name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install flask_mail in order to be able to import it.
if you are working with linux type this into your terminal and hit enter: 
$ sudo pip install flask_mail

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to save time. Upgrade or update your pip before installing Flask-Mail. It worked on my Mac

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

```
pip install Flask-Mail
```