# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mail'

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I am creating a web application where the user will receive a confirmation mail after they've registered.
But I am getting an error in the command line, **Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
**import**(module_name)
File "/home/ubuntu/flask/registration/application.py", line 3, in 
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mail'** and an error on the web page, **Internal Server Error**
*The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

**application.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from cs50 import SQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"] = os.getenv("MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER")
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = os.getenv("MAIL_PASSWORD")
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 587
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = smtp.gmail.com
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = os.getenv("MAIL_USERNAME")
mail = Mail(app)


db = SQL("sqlite:///froshims.db")
REGISTRANTS = {}

SPORT=["Cricket", "Football", "Badminton", "Kho-Kho", "Kabaddi"]

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html", sports = SPORT)
    email = request.form.get("email")
    sport = request.form.get("sport")
    if not email:
        return render_template("failure.html", message="E-mail not entered")
    if not sport:
        return render_template("failure.html", message="Sport not selected")
    if sport not in SPORT:
        return render_template("failure.html", message="Sport not in list. Don't try to hack our website.")
    if request.method == "POST":
        REGISTRANTS[name]=sport
        print("yes")
        db.execute("INSERT INTO registrants (name, sport) VALUES (?,?)", name, sport)
        message = Message("You are registered!", recipients=[email])
        mail.send(message)
        return redirect("success")

@app.route("/success")
def success():
    print("kaam kar na")
    registrants = db.execute("SELECT * FROM registrants")
    return render_template("success.html", registrants = registrants)
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. I am new to Flask. Please guide me.

Comment: try looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585913/importerror-no-module-named-flask-mail) and seeing if any of these answers help you

Comment: actually I was working on cs50 IDE and it was asking the password which I obviously don't know

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I have updated

Comment: first you have to install [Flask-Mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/). Did you install it? `pip install Flask-Mail` or (to make sure it installed for Python 3.9) `pip3.9 install Flask-Mail` or `python3.9 -m pip install Flask-Mail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with **flask_mail** import. pip installing **Flask-Mail** in a virtual environment on a code editor alone might not cause a module import error.
Go to your command line into the app directory
Also, make sure the pip version in your venv environment is up to date.

```
pip install Flask-Mail
```

This worked for me.